# populate sqlite data to recyclerview list

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

I am trying to make a recyclerview list of lectures, and the dataset used is stored in the SQLite database, I don't know what I'm missing but the list adapter still logs zero counts from the list, so the listview doesn't get populated with the items

TeacherActivity

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.icu.util.Calendar;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.planet.noobs.testproject.Adapters.LecListAdapter;
import com.planet.noobs.testproject.Data.DBHelper;
import com.planet.noobs.testproject.Helpers.InputValidation;
import com.planet.noobs.testproject.Model.Lectures;
import com.planet.noobs.testproject.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TeacherActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    LecListAdapter listAdapter;
    private TextInputEditText editTextSubject;
    private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutSubject;
    private AppCompatButton buttonTimeSlot;
    private AppCompatTextView textViewTime;
    private AppCompatButton appCompatButtonSave;
    private TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewLec;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private int mHour, mMinute;
    private Lectures lectures;
    private InputValidation inputValidation;
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    private boolean gotTime = false;
    private List<Lectures> lecturesList;
    private LinearLayout addLecParent;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_teacher);
        getSupportActionBar();

        intiViews();
        initListeners();
        initObjects();
    }

    private void intiViews() {
        textViewTime = (AppCompatTextView) findViewById(R.id.timeView);
        buttonTimeSlot = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.appCompatButtonTimeSlot);
        textInputLayoutSubject = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutSubject);
        editTextSubject = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.appCompatEditTextSubject);
        appCompatButtonSave = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.appCompatButtonSave);
        recyclerViewLec = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listview_lectures);
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.lec_fab);
        addLecParent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_addlec);
    }

    private void initListeners() {
        appCompatButtonSave.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonTimeSlot.setOnClickListener(this);
        fab.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void initObjects() {

        inputValidation = new InputValidation(this);
        lectures = new Lectures();

        lecturesList = new ArrayList<>();
        listAdapter = new LecListAdapter(lecturesList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerViewLec.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerViewLec.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerViewLec.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewLec.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
        refreshItems();
    }

    private void refreshItems(){
        lecturesList.clear();
        lecturesList.addAll(dbHelper.getAllLec());
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.appCompatButtonTimeSlot:
                getTime();
                break;
            case R.id.appCompatButtonSave:
                postDataToDB();
                break;
            case R.id.lec_fab:
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public void getTime() {
        // Get Current Time

        final Calendar c;
        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                textViewTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(hourOfDay)
                        .append(" : ")
                        .append(minute)
                        .append(getAMPM(hourOfDay)));

                textViewTime.setText(textViewTime.getText().toString());
                gotTime = true;
            }
        }, mHour, mMinute, false);
        timePickerDialog.show();
    }

    private String getAMPM(int hourOfDay) {
        String format;
        if (hourOfDay == 0) {
            hourOfDay += 12;
            format = "AM";
        } else if (hourOfDay == 12) {
            format = "PM";
        } else if (hourOfDay > 12) {
            hourOfDay -= 12;
            format = "PM";
        } else {
            format = "AM";
        }
        return format;
    }

    private void postDataToDB() {
        if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextSubject(editTextSubject, textInputLayoutSubject, "Enter the subject first.")) {
            return;
        }
        if (!gotTime) {
            Snackbar.make(recyclerViewLec, "Please select the time", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        lectures.setLecTitle(editTextSubject.getText().toString().trim());
        lectures.setLecDateTime(textViewTime.getText().toString());

        dbHelper.addLec(lectures);
        emptyEditText();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Lecture added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    private void emptyEditText(){
        editTextSubject.setText(null);
        textViewTime.setText(null);
    }

}
```

LecListAdapter

```
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.planet.noobs.testproject.Model.Lectures;
import com.planet.noobs.testproject.R;

import java.util.List;


public class LecListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LecListAdapter.LecViewHolder> {

    private List<Lectures> mlec;

    public LecListAdapter(List<Lectures> mlec) {
        this.mlec = mlec;
    }


    @Override
    public LecViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.teacher_lec_item, parent, false);
        return new LecViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(LecViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textViewLecTime.setText(mlec.get(position).toString());
        holder.textViewSub.setText(mlec.get(position).toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.v(LecListAdapter.class.getSimpleName(), String.valueOf(mlec.size()));
        return mlec.size();
    }

    public class LecViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private AppCompatTextView textViewSub;
        private AppCompatTextView textViewLecTime;
        //private TextView emptyView;
        public LecViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //emptyView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.emptyView);
            textViewSub = (AppCompatTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lec_title);
            textViewLecTime = (AppCompatTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lec_time);
        }
    }
}
```

DbHelper.java

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = "SQL ";
    //databse version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    //database name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserManager.db";
    //table name
    private static final String TABLE_STUDENT = "student";

    //column's name
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME = "user_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_CONTACT = "user_contact";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";
    //create table query
    private static final String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_STUDENT + "(" +
            COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_CONTACT + " NUMBER, " +
            COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";

    //DROP TABLE IF EXISTS
    private static final String DROP_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_STUDENT;

    //Column's name for Books

/*
    private static final String TABLE_BOOKS = "books";

    private static final String COLUMN_BOOK_ID = "user_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_BOOK_TITLE = "book_title";
    private static final String COLUMN_BOOK_DESC = "book_desc";
    private static final String COLUMN_BOOK_ISSUE_DATE = "book_issue_date";

    private static final String CREATE_BOOK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_BOOKS + "(" +
            COLUMN_BOOK_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+ COLUMN_BOOK_ID +
            " Text, "+ COLUMN_BOOK_TITLE + " Text, " + COLUMN_BOOK_ISSUE_DATE + " Text, " +
            COLUMN_BOOK_DESC + " Text" + ")";

    private static final String DROP_BOOKS_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_BOOKS;
*/

    // Columns name for lectures table
    // Table name
    private static final String TABLE_LECTURES = "lectures";

    private static final String COLUMN_LEC_ID = "lec_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_LEC_SUBJECT = "subject";
    private static final String COLUMN_TIME = "lec_time";

    private static final String CREATE_LECTURES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LECTURES + "(" +
            COLUMN_LEC_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_LEC_SUBJECT + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_TIME + " TEXT" + ")";

    private static final String DROP_LECTURES_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LECTURES;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LECTURES_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // drop student table if exist
/*
        db.execSQL(DROP_USER_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DROP_LECTURES_TABLE);
*/
        onCreate(db);
    }
    // Lectures helper methods

    public void addLec(Lectures lectures) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_LEC_SUBJECT, lectures.getLecTitle());
        values.put(COLUMN_TIME, lectures.getLecDateTime());

        db.insert(TABLE_LECTURES, null, values);
        Log.v(DBHelper.class.getSimpleName(),"addlec() is Working!");
        db.close();
    }

    public List getAllLec() {
        String[] COLUMNS = {
                COLUMN_LEC_SUBJECT,
                COLUMN_TIME
        };

        List<Lectures> lecList = new ArrayList<Lectures>();
        String sortOrder = COLUMN_LEC_SUBJECT + " ASC";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                TABLE_LECTURES,
                COLUMNS,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                sortOrder);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Lectures lec = new Lectures();
                lec.setLecTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_LEC_SUBJECT)));
                lec.setLecDateTime(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TIME)));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return lecList;
    }

    public List getAllUser() {
        //columns to be fetched
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_USER_ID,
                COLUMN_USER_EMAIL,
                COLUMN_CONTACT,
                COLUMN_USER_NAME,
                COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD
        };
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

        String sortOrder = COLUMN_USER_NAME + " ASC";
        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                TABLE_STUDENT,
                columns,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                sortOrder
        );

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                User user = new User();
                user.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_ID))));
                user.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_NAME)));
                user.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL)));
                user.setContact(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CONTACT))));
                user.setPasswd(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD)));
                userList.add(user);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return userList;
    }


    // user helpers
    public void addUser(User user) {
        //open database with write permission
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_NAME, user.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD, user.getPasswd());
        values.put(COLUMN_CONTACT, user.getContact());

        db.insert(TABLE_STUDENT, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    /**
     * This method is to delete user record
     *
     * @param user
     */
    public void deleteUser(User user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // delete user record by id
        db.delete(TABLE_STUDENT, COLUMN_USER_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(user.getId())});
        db.close();
    }

    public boolean checkUser(String email) {
        //columns to be fetched
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_USER_ID
        };

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        //selection criteria in where clause
        String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ?";
        //selection arguments
        String[] selection_arg = {
                email
        };

        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                TABLE_STUDENT, // table name
                columns,       // columns to return
                selection,     // Where clause selection
                selection_arg, //Where clause selection value
                null,
                null,
                null
        );

        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return count > 0;

    }

    public boolean checkUser(String email, String passwd) {
        //columns to be fetched
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_USER_ID
        };

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        //selection criteria in where clause
        String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ?" + " AND " + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " = ?";
        //selection arguments
        String[] selection_arg = {
                email,
                passwd
        };

        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                TABLE_STUDENT, // table name
                columns,       // columns to return
                selection,     // Where clause selection
                selection_arg, //Where clause selection value
                null,
                null,
                null
        );

        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return count > 0;

    }
}
```

activity_teacher.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent_addlec"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"

        >

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutSubject"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/appCompatEditTextSubject"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Add Lectures"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLength="15"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/timeView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/appCompatButtonTimeSlot"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Time Slot" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/appCompatButtonSave"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Save" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#ccc" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Lectures Today"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/listview_lectures"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/lec_fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/listview_lectures"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_plus" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check in debug mode, whether you are getting the data from db or not, and in onBindViewHolder() of recyclerview check that data is passed or not. if there is no data, then it is not displaying anything

Comment: All that unnecessary layout nesting is bad for performances.

Comment: Thank you, Sir, I debugged the code and find that all the data flow was working fine  but the actual problem was in the DbHelper class function getAllLec() because the function was not adding any item to the list, so I added this                 lecList.add(lec);

Comment: Any suggestions for improvement @Rotawang

Answer (score 0):

You are passing blank list into your adapter first fill the `LIST` and then use setAdapter method.

```
lecturesList = new ArrayList<>();

RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
recyclerViewLec.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerViewLec.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerViewLec.setHasFixedSize(true);
dbHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
refreshItems();

//setAdapter in last after put data into list.
listAdapter = new LecListAdapter(lecturesList);
recyclerViewLec.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: You were right but the list was empty but the issue was in the Dbhelper.java getAllLec()  so I added <code>lecList.add(lec); </code> before while